# Set maximum amount for specific element without enforcing the order in an XSD Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

We're working on an XSD and have the following situation:

- An element has multiple different SubElements
- One of those SubElements may only show up 1 times
- One of those SubElements may only show up 2 times
- The others are unbound
- We cannot enforce the order of SubElements.

Example of a ValidDataSet:

```
<EL A="1">
   <SUBA B="1"/><!--May only show up once-->
   <SUBB B="1"/><!--May only show up twice-->
   <SUBC B="1"/>
   <SUBB B="1"/>
   <SUBC B="1"/>
</EL>
```

Invalid DataSet:

```
<EL A="1">
   <SUBB B="1"/><!--May only show up twice-->
   <SUBA B="1"/><!--May only show up once-->
   <SUBB B="1"/><!--May only show up twice-->
   <SUBC B="1"/>
   <SUBB B="1"/><!--This is too much -->
   <SUBC B="1"/>
</EL>
```

Is there any way to enforce this with an XSD Schema of Version 1.0?

Here's an example XSD to adjust:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="EL">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="SUBELA" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                            SubElementA
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element ref="SUBELB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                            SubElementA
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element ref="SUBELA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                            SubElementA
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="A" use="required">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        TaskId
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="32"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SUBELA">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="A" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="64"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SUBELB">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="A" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="64"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SUBELC">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="A" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="64"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to enforce this with an XSD Schema of Version 1.0?

No, that's why the feature was added in XSD 1.1, where you can use `xs:all` with minOccurs and maxOccurs values other than 0 or 1.

Actually I think that theoretically it can be done with XSD 1.0, but the complexity of the schema rises exponentially* with the number of elements involved and it quickly becomes quite unmanageable. For example if you have two elements A and B that can each appear once or twice then the content model is something like

```
A(A(B(B?))?|B(AB?|BA?)?)?
```

Add a third element, and higher values for the number of permitted elements, and it quickly gets out of hand.

- (I use the term "exponentially" colloquially, not mathematically. It's probably some kind of combinatorial function, but you get the idea.)